# Javascript: Trigger if confirm return true from different function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to trigger my confirm condition to other function?

myphp.php

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class"button2">

<script>
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
   //my stuff
}else{
   return false;
}
});

$('.button2).on('click', function(){
    //if the confirm condition from first function return true
    //i need to fire here as well without doing another if(confirm)
});
</script>
```

Comment: `if ( true ) { $('.button2).click() }`

Comment: @u_mulder: That way lies unmaintainable spaghetti. :-)

Comment: How about just another named function, that can be called from both event handlers?

Comment: why do you need to register 2 click events for the same button? can't you just resolve it all in one function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you modularize your code by putting the logic you want to use in two places in a function that both places can call:

```
// The function doing the thing
function doTheThing(/*...receive arguments here if needed...*/) {
  // ...
}
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
  if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
     doTheThing(/*...pass arguments here if needed...*/);
  }else{
     return false;
  }
});

$('.button2').on('click', function(){
  //if the confirm condition from first function return true
  //i need to fire here as well without doing another if(confirm)
  doTheThing(/*...pass arguments here if needed...*/);
});
```

---

Side note: I've shown it at the top level of your script, but if you haven't already (and you haven't in your question), I would suggest putting **all** of your code in an immediately-invoked scoping function in order to avoid globals:

```
(function() {
  // The function doing the thing
  function doTheThing(/*...receive arguments here if needed...*/) {
    // ...
  }
  $('#button1').on('click', function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
       doTheThing(/*...pass arguments here if needed...*/);
    }else{
       return false;
    }
  });

  $('.button2').on('click', function(){
    //if the confirm condition from first function return true
    //i need to fire here as well without doing another if(confirm)
    doTheThing(/*...pass arguments here if needed...*/);
  });
})();
```